# Problems with Nan values and Prophet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nan, facebook-prophet, data-preprocessing

I have a database with none values, my intention is to imput (predict) this ausent data with the prophet (treating my database as a time series)

This is the count of ausent data grouped by year:

```
| validTimeUtc | precip1Hour | pressureChange | pressureMeanSeaLevel | relativeHumidity | snow1Hour | temperature | temperatureChange24Hour | temperatureMax24Hour | temperatureMin24Hour | temperatureDewPoint | temperatureFeelsLike | uvIndex | visibility | windDirection | windSpeed | ID_ESTATION | Year | Month | Day |
|--------------|-------------|----------------|----------------------|------------------|-----------|-------------|------------------------|----------------------|----------------------|---------------------|----------------------|---------|------------|---------------|-----------|-------------|------|-------|-----|
| 2015         | 0           | 0              | 0                    | 87760            | 0         | 0           | 0                      | 140                  | 100                  | 100                 | 0                    | 0       | 0          | 0             | 87760     | 0           | 0    | 0     | 0   |
| 2016         | 0           | 20             | 20                   | 174020           | 0         | 20          | 20                     | 20                   | 0                    | 0                   | 20                   | 20      | 20         | 174020        | 0         | 0           | 0    | 0     | 0   |
| 2017         | 0           | 0              | 0                    | 94360            | 0         | 0           | 0                      | 100                  | 0                    | 0                   | 0                    | 0       | 0          | 94360         | 0         | 0           | 0    | 0     | 0   |
| 2018         | 0           | 0              | 0                    | 0                | 0         | 0           | 0                      | 60                   | 0                    | 0                   | 0                    | 0       | 0          | 0             | 0         | 0           | 0    | 0     | 0   |
| 2019         | 0           | 0              | 0                    | 0                | 0         | 0           | 0                      | 60                   | 0                    | 0                   | 0                    | 0       | 0          | 0             | 0         | 0           | 0    | 0     | 0   |
| 2020         | 0           | 0              | 0                    | 0                | 0         | 0           | 0                      | 0                    | 0                    | 0                   | 0                    | 0       | 0          | 0             | 0         | 0           | 0    | 0     | 0   |
| 2021         | 0           | 0              | 0                    | 0                | 0         | 0           | 0                      | 0                    | 0                    | 0                   | 0                    | 0       | 0          | 0             | 0         | 0           | 0    | 0     | 0   |
| 2022         | 0           | 0              | 0                    | 0                | 0         | 0           | 0                      | 0                    | 0                    | 0                   | 0                    | 0       | 0          | 0             | 0         | 0           | 0    | 0     | 0   |
```

My intention was to use prophet changeing the past for the future on the dataframe:

```
df = df_org.copy(deep = True)
df['new_dates'] = df['validTimeUtc'][::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

And instead of one big dataframe, have different dfs depending on one ID, all grouped on a dictionary:

```
groups = df.groupby('ID_ESTATION')

dataframes = {}
for estacion, group in groups:
    dataframes[estacion] = group.drop(group.index[0]).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

After that I use prophet to predict ausent data by columns and join it after all the process:

```
columns = ["precip1Hour", "pressureChange", "pressureMeanSeaLevel", "relativeHumidity", 
           "snow1Hour", "temperature", "temperatureChange24Hour", "temperatureMax24Hour", "temperatureMin24Hour",
           "temperatureDewPoint","temperatureFeelsLike", "uvIndex", "visibility", "windSpeed", "windDirection",
           "ID_ESTATION"]

for estation, df in dataframes.items():
    df_complete = df.copy(deep = True)
    for col in columns:
        print(col)
        df_ausent = df.set_index('validTimeUtc')[df.set_index('validTimeUtc')[col].isnull()]
        df_prophet = df.set_index('validTimeUtc')[~df.index.isin(df_ausent .index)].reset_index().rename(columns={'new_dates': 'ds', col: 'y'})[['ds', 'y']]
        print("--------DATAFRAME-------")
        print(df_prophet)
        
        model = Prophet()
        model.fit(df_prophet)
        predict = df.set_index('validTimeUtc')[df.set_index('validTimeUtc')[col].isnull()].reset_index().rename(columns={'new_dates': 'ds', col: 'y'})[['ds', 'y']]
        print("--------PREDICT-------")
        print(predict)
        if predict.empty:
            pass
        else:
            forecast = model.predict(predict)
            model.plot(forecast)
            print("--------FORECAST-------")
            print(forecast)
            
            df_complete.set_index('validTimeUtc')[col] = df_complete.set_index('validTimeUtc')[col].fillna(forecast.set_index('ds')['yhat'])
    dataframes[estation] = df_complete
        
dataframes
```

With the prints I see that prophet works and make predictions for the ausent data, but when I print the "dataframes" dictionary, I still have Nan values:

```
{0:              validTimeUtc  precip1Hour  pressureChange  pressureMeanSeaLevel  \
 0     2015-06-29 17:20:00          0.0            -0.9                   NaN   
 1     2015-06-29 18:20:00          0.0            -0.1                   NaN   
 2     2015-06-29 19:20:00          0.0             0.5                   NaN   
 3     2015-06-29 20:20:00          0.0             1.2                   NaN   
 4     2015-06-29 21:20:00          0.0             1.3                   NaN   
 ...                   ...          ...             ...                   ...   
 61177 2022-06-30 19:20:00          0.0             2.4                1011.6   
 61178 2022-06-30 20:20:00          0.0             3.8                1013.1   
 61179 2022-06-30 21:20:00          0.0             4.0                1014.4   
 61180 2022-06-30 22:20:00          0.0             3.2                1015.0   
 61181 2022-06-30 23:20:00          0.0             1.9                1015.3   
 
        relativeHumidity  snow1Hour  temperature  temperatureChange24Hour  \
 0                  29.4        0.0         33.6                     -0.7   
 1                  33.2        0.0         31.9                     -0.2   
 2                  39.4        0.0         29.5                     -0.1   
 3                  50.9        0.0         25.4                     -0.7   
 4                  55.6        0.0         23.2                     -0.9   
 ...                 ...        ...          ...                      ...   
 61177              56.8        0.0         23.5                     -1.3   
 61178              70.1        0.0         21.7                     -1.1   
 61179              80.2        0.0         20.5                     -1.3   
 61180              84.7        0.0         20.4                     -0.7   
 61181              92.7        0.0         20.1                     -0.4   
 
        temperatureMax24Hour  temperatureMin24Hour  ...  temperatureFeelsLike  \
 0                      35.5                  18.4  ...                  33.6   
 1                      35.5                  18.4  ...                  31.9   
 2                      35.5                  18.4  ...                  29.7   
 3                      35.5                  18.4  ...                  25.4   
 4                      35.5                  18.4  ...                  23.2   
 ...                     ...                   ...  ...                   ...   
 61177                  30.9                  16.9  ...                  23.5   
 61178                  30.9                  16.9  ...                  21.7   
 61179                  30.9                  16.9  ...                  20.5   
 61180                  30.9                  16.9  ...                  20.4   
 61181                  30.9                  16.9  ...                  20.1   
 
        uvIndex  visibility  windDirection  windSpeed  ID_ESTATION  Year Month  \
 0          1.0       16.09            NaN       16.9            0  2015     6   
 1          0.0       16.09            NaN       15.5            0  2015     6   
 2          0.0       16.09            NaN       13.7            0  2015     6   
 3          0.0       16.09            NaN        9.4            0  2015     6   
 4          0.0       16.09            NaN        6.8            0  2015     6   
 ...        ...         ...            ...        ...          ...   ...   ...   
 61177      0.0       13.78           10.0        5.8            0  2022     6   
 61178      0.0       13.26           20.0        6.8            0  2022     6   
 61179      0.0       12.82           20.0        6.1            0  2022     6   
 61180      0.0       10.14           10.0        6.1            0  2022     6   
 61181      0.0        8.05           20.0        7.2            0  2022     6   
 
       Day           new_dates
 0      29 2022-06-30 22:20:00  
 1      29 2022-06-30 21:20:00  
 2      29 2022-06-30 20:20:00  
 3      29 2022-06-30 19:20:00  
 4      29 2022-06-30 18:20:00  
 ...    ..                 ...  
 61177  30 2015-06-29 20:20:00  
 61178  30 2015-06-29 19:20:00  
 61179  30 2015-06-29 18:20:00  
 61180  30 2015-06-29 17:20:00  
 61181  30 2015-06-29 16:20:0
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.